# HTML click to view and hide bulletin

Tags: html, css

I encountered a problem that puzzles me a lot. I'm writing a web-based tool and in the webpage, I have a bulletin, which when clicked will display or hide recent updates --- i.e., the line of "Click to view/hide bulletin" in the code below. This used to work, but after a few versions, now it does not display updates when clicked. In a parallel webpage, the corresponding part can display/hide updates without problem. I even copied the corresponding part (code is bleow) and put into my page, it still does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mydc.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="thickbox-compressed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="thickbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // some javascript functions here
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="title"><h1>My tool</h1></div>
        <table id="bulletin" class="invis">
             <tr class="invis">
                 <td class="invis">
                     <div id="bulletinslider">
                         <a style="color:red;">
                             Updated 2013.05.04 (Click to view/hide bulletin)</a><br/><br/>
                     </div>
                     <div id="updates" style="display:none;">
                         <u>New changes</u>
                         <ul>
                             <li>some update aaa bbb.</li>
                         </ul><br/>
                         <u>Previous changes</u> (2012.11.27)
                         <ul>
                             <li>some update ccc ddd.</li>
                             <li>some update eee fff.</li>
                             <li>some update ggg hhh.</li>
                             <li>some update iii jjj<br/></li>
                         </ul><br/>
                         <u>Announcements</u>
                         <ul><li>None.</li></ul><br/><br/>
                     </div>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
    <!-- html code with php scripts continue -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And in the css file (mydc.css)

```
.invis {
    background-color:inherit;
    border-style:none;
}
```

Why clicking bulletin does not work?
In addition, I don't quite get how the click on bulletin was triggered.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is the code which triggers the click? And please format the HTML before pasting here..I find it very hard to understand the nesting :-)

Comment: Don't know much about css. suppose in css there should be something for id="bulletinslider" or something for class="invis" to trigger the function of click?   HTML tags reformatted. thanks.

Comment: I think the code to trigger the action lies in javascript .. So add that code to the question as well..and while you're at it,  remove the multiple reference of jquery - you're doing it two times

Comment: will remove one jquery. trying to find the jsp function that controls the click. thanks.

Comment: well, there are only two .js file in the directory (where the clicking update works), and there are jquery-1.7.2.min.js and thickbox-compressed.js, both of them are downloaded online and they don't have (and should not have) the clicking function. I suppose .css file would not control click action, right?

Comment: Maybe/maybe not, you seem to have put a <script> tag in your code. What does that contain?

Comment: just found it. there was a section containing the click function was commented out. Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome! Preparing an answer. Please mark it as the correct answer if it has helped you :-)

Comment: And up vote it if you think it'll help others.:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a `click` event in your JavaScript code. Please check in your code if it exists. You can construct a `click` event to toggle your updared info element like this :

```
$("#bulletinslider a").click( function () {
    //will either show or hide updates div depending on its state currently
    $("#updates").toggle(100);
});
```

CSS cannot perform actions like showing and hiding other elements from its native scope.

So, be sure to check for js `click` events. For more documentation on that click events head over to [jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/click/). Also' read up on [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)